# Waiting for redirect in Javascript (facebook access token)

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, firefox-addon, facebook-authentication

So I'm trying to get an access token from facebook to use with my firefox plugin, so from facebooks point of view I'm a desktop application.

My biggest problem is to detect the redirect to .../login_success.html as I don't know how to do that without crashing firefox.

That's my latest try:

```
function getAuthToken() {
        var app_id = 'MY ID';
        var redirect_uri = 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html';
        var permissions = ['user_photos', 'friends_photos', 
                           'publish_stream', 'offline_access'];
        var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' +
        'client_id=' + app_id + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri + 
        '&scope=' + permissions.join(',') + '&response_type=token';

        window.open(url);

        while(true){
            if(window.onload)
                    if(compareURL(redirec_uri))
                        break;
        }

        var hashStr = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        var arr = hashStr.split('&');

        var accessToken = arr[0];

        return accessToken;
    }

    function compareURL(url)
    {
        if(window.location.href.substring(0, url.length) == url)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Any other way to wait for/detect that redirect to login_success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your browser crashes, it might be because an "infinite" loop is detected and the page becomes unresponsive. Maybe you should try

```
window.setInterval(function()
{
  // check your redirect url and so on
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Ok, didn't work as I thought. The function terminates and that doesn't mean that the variable access_token is set to something useful.
I need the token on termination of this function.